# Lower semicontinuous integer valued function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, reference-request

I remember reading in some book a characterization of **lower semicontinuous functions** that are **integer valued** (for example, rank of a matrix), along the lines that it can either not jump abruptly or not fall abruptly. I did not understand this at the time and I cannot recall the precise statement. Could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kato (Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators, 1984, pp 209) says that the spectrum of an operator is upper semicontinuous and that this means that the spectrum cannot expand suddenly but it may well shrink suddenly.

If rank is seen as a complement to spectrum, then it appears that rank cannot decrease suddenly, it can only increase.

Answer (score 0):

$f: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called upper semicontinuous if $f^{-1}((-\infty,t))$ is open for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. if $f(x)<t$ then there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ s.t. $f(y)<t$ for all $y \in U$.

In your case, $f: X \longmapsto \mathbb{Z}$ being upper semicontinuous means that if $f(x)=n$ then there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ s.t. $f(y) \leq n$ for all $y \in U$, i.e. $f$ is non-increasing.